# Find second occurrence of text using syncfusion-react document editor.(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syncfusion

Need to find the second occurrence of the text using sync-fusion document editor and highlight the text in red color.

As per the document they have findAll() method, it finds the text in whole document and highlight in yellow color. Is there anyway that i can customize the highlight color and find only second occurrence in the document?.

```
replaceAll() {
    let textToFind = document.getElementById('find_text').value;
    let textToReplace = document.getElementById('replace_text').value;
    if (textToFind !== '') {
        // Find all the occurences of given text
        this.documenteditor.searchModule.findAll(textToFind);
        if (this.documenteditor.searchModule.searchResults.length > 0) {
            // Replace all the occurences of given text
            this.documenteditor.searchModule.searchResults.replaceAll(textToReplace);
        }
    }
}
render() {
    return (<div>
            <button onClick={this.replaceAll.bind(this)}>Replace All</button>
            <DocumentEditorComponent id="container" ref={(scope) => { this.documenteditor = scope; }} isReadOnly={false} enableSelection={true} enableEditor={true} enableSearch={true}/>
        </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After performing search operation using find and findall.

You can customize the search results. Kindly refer the below documentation.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/document-editor/find-and-replace/?no-cache=1#search-results

Try setting the index in search results. Though all the text will be highlighted, and selection alone will be highlighted on text occurrence based on index. Please check the above documentation whether it suits your requirement or kindly share your use case scenario on finding the second occurrence.

Also, document editor doesn’t provide any customization option on highlighting the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding customizing the search result

Latest version(17.4.49) of document editor provides option to customize search highlight color.
Please refer the below sample code

this.settings = { 
        searchHighlightColor:'red' 
};

DocumentEditorContainerComponent id="container" ref={(scope) => { this.container = scope; }} style={{ 'display': 'block', 'height': '590px' }} documentEditorSettings={this.settings} enableToolbar={true} locale='en-US'/>

Release notes

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/release-notes/17.4.49/#document-editor

This helps you to customize the highlight color of search results